# Kubectl command hangs not able to delete pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

I am running a command like below

`kubectl run -i --rm --pod-running-timeout=5m busy-box-pod --restart=Never --image=busybox --command -- sh -c "env"`

sometime the command executes and removes the pod but sometimes its hangs in Error/Completed/Running state
not sure what is the issue causing this. is --rm not working?

below are my versions

```
Client Version: v1.18.8
Server Version: v1.17.6
```

Comment: Use the verbosity flag `kubectl --v=2 ....`  (verbosity can be set between 0-9) when passing the command to check what happens exactly .

Comment: Ive run multiple times your command and never have issue. Could you provide more details about your environment? Its `Kubeadm` or `Minikube` ? Do you have all default settings or you have some specific configuration? Can you share output of `kubectl logs <podname>`? Can you `kubectl describe <podname>`? Also do you see anything strange in `kubectl get events`? Debugging guide you can find in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/)

Comment: @PjoterS its Kubeadm, i have hard time reproducing it but when this runs as part of a batch process we are seeing sporadic occurrences of these hangs, i have two containers inside the POD and the logs, describe just show 1/2 running even though the process completed and sometimes 0/2 completed with both the process completed but not getting deleted

Comment: Would be possible to provide your YAMLs?  it might be some specific flag in your yaml. Command you provided earlier is creating only 1 container. Also, could you provide your environment resources (Ram, CPU)?